# Composer errors on ubuntu hosted on VMware, how can I disable openssl

Tags: openssl, composer-php, ssl-certificate, lamp, vmware-workstation

I'm working in a company that apply security restrictions. And I need to establish LAMP environment on VMware (ubuntu 16.04 hosted on VMware workstation 14 pro, on Windows 10). The main problem I faced is internet openssl and certificate verify. Everything thing is working with me fine, expect running composer.
When I run `composer update`, I got this error
[image]

And when I run `composer install`, I got this error
[image]

How can I disable openssl and certificate verify to proceed with the installation process?

Comment: Do you have openssl installed?

Comment: @gview Yes It's installed